# FEA software for Orthotropic materials

Tags: finite-element-method, solidworks, wood

What FEA software is capable of simulating static studies on orthotropic materials such as wood? I must be able to define mechanical properties in X,Y and Z. I would also like to have access to failure criteria such as tsai-hill or tsai-wu and probably even other custom criteria. My company uses solid edge simulation at the moment but i have not found a way to account for orthotropic materials, I also tried solidworks simulation on my side and I was able to perform most of what i need but i want to consider any additional options before i make a recommendation to my company to shift to a new software.
Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the major FEA systems (Nastran, Abaqus, Ansys, Adina, Comsol, etc) can do this. If you have a fairly limited requirements (e.g. only linear statics), look for the vendor with the cheapest entry-level or student-level version of the code which includes orthotropic material models.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these.  Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Abaqus Standard or Abaqus Explicit (depending on the type of problem you are trying to solve).  Ansys Workbench should also have the features you need.

Cost will be around $20000 per year.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is indeed very helpful. I've seen a couple of demos and Abaqus seems to be everything one could ever wish for in an FEA software, however I will be running simple static load tests on structural frames made of solid timber and engineering woods so probably Abaqus is an overkill (not to mention unaffordable). I will probably be ok with solidworks sim professional for now.